# What happened to get this mod notice placed on my question about the Bête?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comments, moderation, post-notice

I had asked a totally valid question with [The Bête and LGBT-Questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132639/the-b%c3%aate-and-lgbt-questions), and after a short explanation why this was asked without an edition (because there is soo little on the topic) and a comment that was totally off-topic (and disturbing) I noticed a comment that **3** of our diamonds had to look into the question already and pointing out that comments are for clarification only. I know that the topic does not sit right with some people, but this sounds like people flagged it for some reason or another.

To be clear: that is **not** a political question, I **never** asked people to take a position on the topic. All I ask for is help finding the explicit and implicit information on this topic.

But it still made me wonder: What motivated our diamonds to place that comment?

(note: If there are deleted answers, I can't see them yet)

Comment: For what it's worth, there aren't any deleted answers. Whatever silliness went over there, it was in the comments.

Comment: Should also be noted that the diamonds are generally reluctant to provide a lot of information about previous moderation incidents, eg. "why was X's account suspended last year" or "what offensive stuff did Y actually post". It's a pragmatic policy. You probably won't get much detail.

Comment: Just as a completely side note, “Staff” and “Mods” are different people. Staff are employees of SE, while mods are volunteer site members.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not a huge amount has actually happened beyond the weird comments you flagged. There was not a huge explosion you missed. But there's current weirdness, and the topic may get controversial, so it looks like a case of applying a version of [the controversial post notice](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/id-like-to-introduce-you-to-our-new-friend-the-controversial-topic-post-notic). Basically we see more trouble potentially brewing.

That's not on you though or the question—it's a fair question to ask. Interpersonal.SE has found LGBT posts can draw some controversy at the best of times, and this one digs straight into LGBT controversy (how do various groups feel about LGBT groups?) so it's probably a good idea to just safely and proactively have a notice there.

Comment: and I thought that someone did throw in an answer/comment that was very political that I missed.

Comment: I might add that having three mods see a post that's drawn even one flag isn't terribly unusual. Site members may not know, but we all get a notification for every flag and so if a flag isn't immediately acted upon/resolved by the first mod to see it, it's not at all unusual for 3 or 4 of us to "see a flagged post" pretty quickly.